# How do i pass a union of arrays to a generic function taking an array?

Tags: flowtype

Consider the definitions:

```
interface HasNumber {
  getNumber(): number;
};

function getNumber<T: HasNumber>(x: T): number {
  return x.getNumber();
}

class X implements HasNumber {
  getNumber(): number { return 1; }
}

class Y implements HasNumber {
  getNumber(): number { return 2; }
}
```

Passing a variable of type `X | Y` to `getNumber` works as expected:

```
let x: X | Y;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  x = new X();
} else {
  x = new Y();
}
getNumber(x);
```

However, with the definition

```
function getNumberSum<T: HasNumber>(x: T[]): number {
  let n = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { n += x[i].getNumber(); }
  return n;
}
```

passing a variable of type `X[] | Y[]` to `getNumberSum` doesn't seem to work:

```
let xs: X[] | Y[];
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  xs = ([new X()]: X[]);
} else {
  xs = ([new Y()]: Y[]);
}
getNumberSum(xs);
```

The error (from the [try page](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gASxAzgHICuAtgEaFgDeqYYA5njkatCACgCUALjBZmbAgG5UAX0WooDLKRwY4WPgKFyAPABUp1erMIA+EQA8pJydKsFO3MAQEMCeuwDp+QVdxRSV0UhhaGjAADTAMJgAHGDwmPFwYi0N2Lh4gnIJxKRlhNw5Pb18wAEZ5MHDw1EjosABNBOTU9MyqWkL3fIMQ51K5TkqcHz0AJnrG9AKQrDwkWPExRSWykRWkNo3VVJwwBziwAB92xQwoMBEAWWIcAAt-AmIsABM4JnEwaxgAAM-gArGJBqcwABeaSrOKhZRgPAwGgUPJQ2F7dqI8LbOT2TbodSabS6fTBMoAZWYpnM-VctjOJgA2gBdUauSHHaQw4GKHhQOBuEQ8jB8oH1cVGU7+VJYXivKUAamVEIqemVsLsLIwbMCwx2mwaHi8U2qWDCi0NchpfxZ2PWYg5WxthDtIgd8IOzqJqB5dhoUli7Mu7XZNzuj2ebw+31+-0BIPBkMDfM9jvEbOD7KJSmRqPRHjTsIz3qzUjauat+PdzHsNCJQA)) is:

```
45: getNumberSum(xs);
                 ^ array type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
30: function getNumberSum<T: HasNumber>(x: T[]): number {
                                           ^ array type
Type argument `T` is incompatible:
41:   xs = ([new X()]: X[]);
                       ^ X. This type is incompatible with
43:   xs = ([new Y()]: Y[]);
                       ^ Y
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of Flow? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I'd just define `xs` as `let xs: HasNumber[];` and get rid of additional annotation on array creation `xs = [new X()];`

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately, as I need to express that all the elements of an array are the same type, not just that they implement `HasNumber`.

Comment: Can you show specific use case? In your example it definitely not required.

Comment: Imagine the interface were something like `CanAdd<+T> { add(b: T): T }` and the function were `getSum<T: CanAdd<*>>(arr: T[]): T`. Passing a `CanAdd[]` to `getSum` won't work since there's no guarantee that they're all the same type.